# NVIDIA NeMO container Intent / Slots Filling training issue

Tags: nlp, nvidia, nlp-question-answering

I setup the **NVIDIA** `nvcr.io/nvidia/nemo:23.06` container, started jupyter, I can go through all steps of the notebook Joint Intent and Slot Filling, GPU is recognized

but if I run training then only 1 epoch there are any changes, all other *epoches* the same test result and even after 50 epochs nothing new!, nothing comparable with results mentioned in the notebook.

how should I proceed to find the issue?
Thank you in advance